# How to create a reusable plot_ly function?

Tags: r, function, plotly

I am looking at a dataset from tidytuesday, available here:

```
video_games <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2019/2019-07-30/video_games.csv")
```

I wrote this code to create a horizontal bar plot, ranked in descending order.

```
video_games %>% 
  top_n(10, metascore) %>% 
  arrange(desc(metascore)) %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~metascore, y = ~fct_reorder(game, metascore), 
          type = "bar") %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Metascore"),
         yaxis = list(title = ""))
```

I want to reuse the code with multiple variables without copying and pasting, so I created a function with 2 entries for the variables I want to plot. (I left out the layout section.  If there is a way to automatically re-lable the plot inside the function, that would be cool.)

```
video_games_ranking_plot <- function(A, B) {
  top_n(10, A) %>% 
    arrange(desc(A)) %>% 
    plot_ly(x = ~A, y = ~fct_reorder(B, A), 
            type = "bar")
}
```

When I run the function

```
video_games %>%           
video_games_ranking_plot(metascore, game)
```

... I get the error message `Error in video_games_ranking_plot(., metascore, game) : 
  unused argument (game)`

Does anyone know why?

Comment: For what it's worth, I get the same error when the function is simply: video_games_ranking_plot <- function(A, B) {
plot_ly(x = ~A, y = ~B, 
            type = "bar")
}

Comment: Also, the arrange(desc(...)) call can be removed, as the resulting plot is the same without it.

Answer (score 2):

The source of the problem seems to be that you are passing the same arguments `metascore, game` of **one type** to very different elements of your custom function that accepts arguments of ***different types***:

1. `top_n(10, metascore)`
2. `arrange(desc(metascore)`
3. `plot_ly(x = ~metascore, y = ~fct_reorder(game, metascore)`

The fact that you are also passing columns ase arguments using piping can also pose certain challenges. I haven't found the time to build a complete solution, but hopefully this will help you on your way to a complete solution:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(plotly)

# get data
video_games <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2019/2019-07-30/video_games.csv")

data <- video_games

# custom function
video_games_ranking_plot <- function(data, topn, col_top, col_ord){

  # select and arrand data
  df <- data %>% top_n(topn, {{col_top}}) %>% arrange(desc({{col_ord}})) #%>%

  col_top_name <- deparse(substitute(col_top))
  col_ord_name <- deparse(substitute(col_ord))
  df2<- df[c(col_top_name, col_ord_name)]

  # build plotly pliot
  p <- plot_ly(x = df2[[col_top_name]], y = df2[[col_ord_name]], type = "bar")


}

plt <- video_games_ranking_plot(data=video_games, topn=5, metascore, game)  

plt
```

There's still an issue with the `~fct_reorder(game, metascore)` part.
I had to raise a question myself to even get this far. Take a look at the answer from user Ronak Shah to the post [How to pass a dataframe column as an argument in a function using piping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59767759/how-to-pass-a-dataframe-column-as-an-argument-in-a-function-using-piping) to learn more on how to pass arguments to piping functions.

I hope this helps!